# How to break on variable change in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, xdebug

Is there any way to break on variable getting changed?
E.g. Variable $abc is used and modified in many different functions and files, when I debug a large project, I want to know when it get changed exactly.

Setting breakpoints can only tell me what the value is at that point, but I want to know the whole life of this variable.

Comment: I think you want to look at setting a conditional breakpoint.

Comment: @Drumbeg not if I have this variable in hundreds of places...

Comment: maybe `spl_object_hash()` is what you're looking for

Comment: @djay Do you have any idea how I can combine it with XDebug?

Answer (score -1):

Please search for 'php debugger'.

But I don't use one.  It's relatively easy to search your source base for that variable and then use var_dump()'s to display when a variable is it's getting changed.  Do you know how to use the Search all files feature in Notepad++?

Then once you've found your problem, use the undo to restore the files, and take the var_dumps() back out.

I also often put a die in places to stop so I can know for sure where a particular var_dump is executing.

I keep a Debug variable in my ini file and have a way to easily turn it on and off, and then can watch certain variables with if($ini['Debug']) var_dump($myvar);

There are some advantages to doing things this way rather than with a debugger.  First your code runs faster, and this can matter depending on the complexity of your code.  Second, it always works, no matter how strange your code, whereas there are sometimes things that can fool a debugger.

Comment: Of course you can use var_dump if the project is not large...when you get hundreds of occurrences after running a "Find in all files", you won't want to use var_dump again.

Comment: If you have that many occurrences, a debugger might not be help much as it will stop all over the place???

Comment: A debugger is more convenience but still not helpful enough. I don't need to type var_dump() all over the place but I still need to set breakpoints and step into/over all the time.

Comment: Sometimes I even use bisection method to locate where the variable changes exactly... the function body can be very very long...

Comment: 'bisection'?  Is that what I call divide and conquer, or a binary search?  If so I often use that too if I don't otherwise know where to start.  But I prefer well commented and structured code as I find it easier to get working.  Years ago I used a debugger lots.  Even wrote a really good one.  But don't find use for it much anymore with better codding techniques.  And I also work on a large project with 28k lines of code.

Comment: hah,yes. Sadly the project I'm reusing isn't well-documented. It has about 500k lines of code including PHP,HTML and JS. I find it pretty hard to read and figure out what each variable or function does. In fact I didn't use PHP debugger before...